# Continuity of the function $f(x)=x^{2}+2x-2$ if $x\in\mathbb{Q}$ and $f(x)=3x$ if $x\in\mathbb{I}$

Tags: calculus

I need help with the following.

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\longrightarrow{\mathbb{R}}$  defined by $f(x)=x^{2}+2x-2$ if $x\in\mathbb{Q}$ and $f(x)=3x$ if $x\in\mathbb{I}$

I need to determine the points where $f$ is continuous and the points where $f$ is discontinuous.

I am really confused, any help?

Comment: Hint: $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$, and when do you have $x^2 + 2x - 2 = 3x$?

Comment: ok, I find the solutions, the solutions are the points of continuity right?, but why is that?

Comment: because for any $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$, there is a rational number arbitrarily close to it, and there is an irrational number arbitrarily close to it, that is what "dense" means.

Answer (score 1):

The function is continuous whenever $ x^2 + 2x - 2 = 3x $. If $ x = x_0 $ satisfies this equality, then the limit exists at $ x_0 $.

If $ x^2 + 2x - 2 = 3x $, then taking any sequence of real number approaching $ x $ and applying $ f $ to the members of the sequence will result in two subsequences depending on whether or not the members of the sequence are rational or not. However, both subsequences approach the value of $ f(x) $, because the two parts of the piecewise function are themselves continuous.

If it is not the case that $ x^2 + 2x - 2 = 3x $, then the two subsequences will not approach the same value.

Hence, it is continuous at $ x = -1, 2 $.

By the way, $ \mathbb{I} $ typically denotes the set of pure imaginary numbers. It would be more appropriate to just use $ \mathbb{R} \backslash \mathbb{Q} $.

Comment: "If $ x = x_0 $ satisfies this equality, then the limit exists at $ x_0 $". Sorry, can you explain me this? I really don't get it.

Comment: I see that it is true, but formal argument would be?